# Oracle - ASP sql command not properly ended

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I am very new to Oracle and asp. I am trying to run a small MySQL query. But getting the error

```
ORA-00933 SQL Command not properly Ended
```

My query is

```
SELECT * FROM NAME_TBL WHERE username = 'admin';
```

I googled and tried all the options. The query running perfectly when it executed in Oracle SQL Developer

Please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to remove the ending semicolon

Comment: hi. thanks for your reply.. can you please tell me how to read the data from table and show in my page ? Please